# comparing two files character by character

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Type first file name to use: ");
    String filename1 = console.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type second file name to use: ");
    String filename2 = console.nextLine();
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(filename1));
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(filename2));
    String s1 = input1.next();
    String s2 = input2.next();
    boolean similar=true;r
while(!input1.hasNext()&&!input2.hasNext()){
// this is where i am stuck. i need to compare the lines character by character, but i'm not sure how to do so. i can't use buffer method, or any really advanced methods since i am just a beginner, so sticking to the basic loops (while, iff, for.. ) is the only option i have
}
```

the program should prompt the user to enter two file names and prints true or false depending on whether or not the files have the same contents.It should check the files character by character and ignore difference (upper case and lower case) in the case of the characters that are letters. thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you could Hash the file and compare the Hash's to save a lot of time or overhead.

Comment: Assuming you only have problems in the line you commented, your question is really "how do I compare two strings". In that case, use equals: `if ( ! input1.next().equals(input2.next())) { /* not-equal */ }`. If your really need char by char, use a loop on their characters, extracted via, say, `input1.next().toCharArray()`

Comment: @user2860598: Hashing requires going over the complete file, so it's less efficient in this case.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: @EyalSchneider Isn't going over a file line-by-line exactly the same as going over the complete file?

Comment: @user2860598: If you compare char by char, you can quit once you identify a mismatch. When calculating hash values, you have to go over the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) {
    // All characters on the entire line are equal.
} else {
    // There is a difference
}
```

It will compare the strings character by character one line at a time.

You can create a loop but that would require more code and would result in worse performance.

Comment: i just add this in my while loop? or should i create a boolean method that returns true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Character by character and not allowing current structures to do any of the work?, how about...

```
while(!input1.hasNext()&&!input2.hasNext())
{
  char c1 = input1.next(".");
  char c2 = input2.next(".");

  if (c1!=c2)
  {
    //Files are not equal
  }
}
```

Comment: kind of overkill to use next("aRegex") instead of looping over charAt(i) -- although Java may be doing some nice caching of the regexes to avoid all that object creation and removal.

Comment: For efficiency I agree with you.  OP looks like a beginner though and a regex solution is just going to be confusing.  I tried to go for a simple and easily digestible solution that OP can modify once they understand the idea.

Comment: but next(".") is equivalent to next(Pattern.compile(".")) -- you are in fact advocating for the use of regexes

Comment: Meh, you're right. I'm obviously not thinking straight.  My solution also is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could process files char-by-char if you like, using instance of `Reader`.
Something like :

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName1"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName2"));
int char1; // from first file
int char2; // from second file
// loop until the end of either file is reached
while ((char1 = reader1.read()) != -1 && (char2 = reader2.read()) != -1) {
    // convert current characters from both files to lowerCase
    char lowerCase1 = Character.toLowerCase((char) char1);
    char lowerCase2 = Character.toLowerCase((char) char2);
    if (lowerCase1 != lowerCase2) {
        System.out.println("your text files are different!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not allowed to use Reader

Answer (score 0):

You should do smth like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Type first file name to use: ");
    String filename1 = console.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type second file name to use: ");
    String filename2 = console.nextLine();
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(filename1));
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(filename2));
    String s1 = input1.next();
    String s2 = input2.next();
    boolean similar=true;r
    while(!input1.hasNext()&&!input2.hasNext()){
        if (a.findInLine(".").compareToIgnoreCase(b.findInLine(".")) != 0) {
            similar = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (similar && (a.hasNext() || b.hasNext())) // unequal sizes
        similar = false;
    System.out.println("Files are " + (similar ? "equal" : "unequal"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Predator44 Edited to be almost working solution. Sorry, untested, but should work.